# Lazyload background image, remove data-src onload

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to lazyload several background images on a page. I am taking the background image from a data attribute `data-src`. When the image is loaded, I'd like to remove the `data-src` data attribute:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {

    $.fn.loadbgimg = function () {
        $('.jumbo[data-src]').each(function(index) {

            var top_of_object = $(this).offset().top;
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object in the window */
            if( bottom_of_window > top_of_object ) {   

                // get datasrc  
                datasrc = $(this).data('src'); 

                // replace bg with data-src
                $(this).css("background-image", "url('" + datasrc + "')"); 

                // remove data-src when img loaded
                $(this).on('load', function() {

                   $(this).removeAttr('data-src');

                });


            }
        });
    };

    $('.jumbo').loadbgimg();

    /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll( function(){

        $('.jumbo').loadbgimg();

    });

});
```

Everything seems to work ok except the last part 'remove data-src when img loaded'. This is doing nothing. The data attribute is not being removed. Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background images don't have a load event. The normal way around this is to create an image element, don't add it to the DOM but set the src attribute. Then handle the load event of that and when it's loaded set the background image url. Because you've already loaded the image it will use your cache, instead of downloading it again. You can remove the data-src attribute at that point.

Here's an example...

```
var $this = $(this);
var datasrc = $this.data('src'); 

// create an image so we have something with a load event
var $img = $("<img/>");

// handle the load event - remove the data-src attribute
$img.on("load", function() {

    // replace bg with data-src
    $this.css("background-image", "url('" + datasrc + "')"); 

    // remove data-src when img loaded
    $this.removeAttr('data-src');
});

// load the image in memory
$img.attr("src", datasrc);
```

Comment: No problem - glad I could help :)